# Get the number between specified strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Ok. Given the example of:

http://example.com/news/3226-some-post-title.html

I'm trying to get the 3226. This regexp: http://interaktywnie.com/newsy/(.*).html
doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
/http:\/\/example\.com\/news\/(\d+)-.+\.html/
```

So:

```
match = /http:\/\/example\.com\/news\/(\d+)-.+\.html/.match("http://example.com/news/3226-some-post-title.html")
puts match[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use:

```
   /\/(\d+)-(.*)\.html$/
```

This will grab the digits (\d) after the '/' and put the digits into the first variable once it finds them.

A great place to test regular expression is http://rubular.com/.

Comment: you need to escape that last .

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
/http:\/\/example.com\/news\/(\d+)-.+\.html/
```

\d is any digit.  Also, the following site is very useful for regular expressions in ruby:

http://www.rubular.com

Answer (score 1):

```
"http://example.com/news/3226-some-post-title.html".split("/").last.to_i
```